# Spring webclient throwing unsupported mediatype exception when trying to convert bodyToMono<UUID>, POST request

Tags: java, post, kotlin, spring-webclient

I am trying to consume an api using spring-webclient. below is my code.code is in kotlin

```
webClient.post()
.uri(“some url”)
.body(Mono.just(request))
.retrieve()
**.bodyToMono<UUID>()**
.awaitSingle()
```

it is throwing error below

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.UUID

If i am trying to convert in to string it is working fine. code below

```
webClient.post()
.uri(“some url”)
.body(Mono.just(request))
.retrieve()
**.bodyToMono<String>()**
.awaitSingle()
```

Response I am expecting from the API is below

```
"response": {
"headers": {
  "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
},
"status": 200,
"body": "6ea4c979-5e05-4e72-9007-c4644bef5672"
```

}

Comment: i think spring boot is expecting application/json if you try to deserialize it.

Comment: Then how it is working for String type ?

Comment: content type string could be transfered into a string without a problem .. but how should the framework know, the structure of the text for creating an object of it .. could be json, something binary, xml anything

Comment: Okay. Thank you let me check.

Comment: you could use objectMapper yourself to create an object if its JSON

Comment: is there any way to receive it as UUID in text/plain format other than parsing from client side /

Comment: i don't know .. but maybe using a HttpMessageConverter?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that exception because the response content type is `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` and not `application/json` as stated in the exception message you posted. In the exception message it also says you are trying to parse the response body to a UUID. I am not sure why you want to do it and it will fail because the response body cannot be mapped to a UUID class/object but this is another issue.

So to solve your main issue at the moment, you need to tell Jackson to accept `text/plain` as it was `application/json` and for that you need to set the codec in the `exchangeStrategies` method when building uo the `WebClient`.

Check the code below, it should fix your issue.

```
WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(this::acceptedCodecs).build())
                .build();


private void acceptedCodecs(ClientCodecConfigurer clientCodecConfigurer) {
        clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
        clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
    }
```